# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox+ObjectCollection' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I began to show my `DataGrid` on a form is created I would like when I course `id`, `rollno`. or `enroll` no but when I execute this code than show the following problem:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox+ObjectCollection' to data type int

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "select COURSE_Id, ROLL_NO, ENROLL_NO, Sub_P_CODE, STUDENT_NA, th_a_o, th_b_o, th_c_o " +
        "FROM annual_2018 " +
        "where COURSE_ID = '" + course_id.Items.ToString() + "' " +
        "and  (ROLL_NO = '" + txtRoll.Text + "' OR ENROLL_NO = '" + TxtEnroll.Text + "')",
        con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    Enroll_no.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: you can send just one value to COURSE_ID. It seems at it stands Items that here are more items and the ToString() will convert that to ObjectCollection not to the value you excpect.

Comment: And read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820944/how-do-i-re-write-a-sql-query-as-a-parameterized-query

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer. Check this link to know How does accepting an answer work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

You have passed the whole `ComboBox`, you need to specify the `SelectedValue` of your `ComboBox`. Your `COURSE_ID` column in the table is an int datatype and that is what you need to pass it. Also you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your code should be something like this:

```
int selectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(course_id.SelectedValue.ToString());

cmd = new SqlCommand("select COURSE_Id, ROLL_NO, ENROLL_NO, Sub_P_CODE, STUDENT_NA," +
                     " th_a_o, th_b_o, th_c_o FROM annual_2018 where COURSE_ID = @courseId" +
                     " and  (ROLL_NO = @ROLL_NO  OR ENROLL_NO = @ENROLL_NO)", con);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseId", selectedValue );
//Other parameters
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`. See this [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@courseId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = selectedValue;
```

Comment: Obligatory reference: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @PeterB Thanks. Yes, I was searching for that link also.