# Pulling sql data from [columnnr] to a string for a later check

Tags: c#, sql, string, winforms

I'm creating a small app. Until now I've had admin users hardcoded into the app, but I have the columns ready in the sql db to check if a user is admin or have edit rights. I'm just having trouble getting that info drawn out of the db.
And wanted to move on to being able to dynamically change admin users.

Heres the code from the app's Load

```
private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (labelUser.Text.Contains("JAM") == true)
        {
            btnAdmin.Visible = true;
            btnUpdate.Visible = true;
            btnNew.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (labelUser.Text.Contains("DST") == true)
        {
            btnAdmin.Visible = true;
            btnUpdate.Visible = true;
            btnNew.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (labelUser.Text.Contains("KBW") == true)
        {
            btnAdmin.Visible = true;
            btnUpdate.Visible = true;
            btnNew.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (labelUser.Text.Contains("JDJ") == true)
        {
            btnAdmin.Visible = true;
            btnUpdate.Visible = true;
            btnNew.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (labelUser.Text.Contains("THR") == true)
        {
            btnAdmin.Visible = true;
            btnUpdate.Visible = true;
            btnNew.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnAdmin.Visible = false;
            btnUpdate.Visible = false;
            btnNew.Visible = false;
        }

        //SQLconnection string
        string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf";

        //SQLconnection
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
        string strCmd = "select * from AvSites";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //Fill combobox list with items from the SQL database
        da.Fill(ds);
        combo1.ValueMember = "id";
        combo1.DisplayMember = "siteName";
        combo1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        combo1.Enabled = true;
        this.combo1.SelectedItem = -1;
        this.combo1.SelectedText = "--select--";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        //SQLconnection
        labelUser2.Text = labelUser.Text.ToLower();
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
        string strCmd2 = "select * from tbl_Login where UserName =  'labelUser2.Text' ";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strCmd2, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd2, con);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string IsAdmin = rdr["IsAdmin"].ToString();
                labelisAdmin.Text = IsAdmin;
            }
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

My first thought was to identify what user, by using my labelUser which is a visible label showing the user currently logged in taken directly from the sqldatabase. (reason for the .ToLower is that the sql db has the users in all small case).

First part of the sql is populating a combobox with items from another db tree.

It's this part that is causing me issues;

```
//SQLconnection
    labelUser2.Text = labelUser.Text.ToLower();
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(cs);
    con.Open();
    string strCmd2 = "select * from tbl_Login where UserName =  'labelUser2.Text' ";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strCmd2, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd2, con);
    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string IsAdmin = rdr["IsAdmin"].ToString();
            labelisAdmin.Text = IsAdmin;
        }
    }

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

}
```

IsAdmin or column [3] is either 0 for false or 1 for true. but with this search, it doesnt return anything.

Comment: You probably don't have a UserName in your database equal to labelUser2.Text. I'm not talking what the label is displaying, You're actually looking for a user named 'labelUser2.Text'.

Comment: Use command with parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Another help on how to write a parameterized query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820944/how-do-i-re-write-a-sql-query-as-a-parameterized-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong

```
string strCmd2 = "select * from tbl_Login where UserName =  'labelUser2.Text' ";
```

because you are actually looking for someone with a username of labelUser2.Text and not what that label's text property contains.

You were probably meaning to concatenate that into your string but that too is wrong. Although it would work, it is a very unsafe practice to get started with. Instead you would place a parameter into your sql statement and give it the value of your label.

```
string strCmd2 = "select * from tbl_Login where UserName = @un ";
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strCmd2, con);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@un", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = labelUser2.Text
SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd2, con);
```

...

Here we put a parameter in place to take in user inputted value, we then create the command object and define the parameters values from the user input controls.